# Configure EJB3 with web.xml like parameters

Tags: java, xml, parameters, ejb-3.0

I'd like to pass some parameters to a stateless session bean. I'd like to do something like I do when I configure a Servlet initial parameters in the web.xml file. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is traditional to use a property file for this.

Comment: Ok, this is probably a stupid question, but how can I load the file from the EJB inside? If I white File f = new File("./file.properties"); it don't work, but I don't know how to access the context to retrive the real path. Can you help me?

Comment: You use an "absolute" path.  For example /config/file.properties.  Also, note there is a Properties class that you should use instead of new File so it abstracts away the parsing.

I should have mentioned that "env-entry" exists for the ejb-jar.xml.  Most people don't use that because it is easier to have a property file vary across environments than the xml that is jar'd up within your ear.

Comment: but wouldn't accessing the file system affect the portability of the app?

Comment: @Stratwine: Not if it is deployed with the app.  This isn't a random file on the file system. T his is a properties file deployed either in the ear or better yet to a directory that can be easily changed.  But that's a rich topic and not something easy to discuss in comments.